# How do I have 2 averages based on different conditions in a query

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to find out the average time per month it takes for someone to complete a task but where one group of people have a disability where as the other group don't.

I have a temp table named #Temp that holds the unique identifier for each person that holds a disability. The join value `Number` is the unique identifier for each person.

The query currently looks like;

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Temp

SELECT *
INTO #Temp
FROM [Table]
WHERE [Disability] = 'Y'

SELECT [MonthName]
, AVG(DATEDIFF(DAY, [DateStarted], [DateEnded])) AS [Average Length In Days For Completion For Disabled Users]
FROM TableName
LEFT JOIN #Temp AS T ON T.[Number] = [Number]
LEFT JOIN [Calendar] AS Cal ON Cal.[Date] = [DateStarted]
WHERE [DateStarted] >= '20220101'
AND T.[Disability] = 'Y'
GROUP BY [MonthName]
ORDER BY [MonthName]


SELECT [MonthName]
, AVG(DATEDIFF(DAY, [DateStarted], [DateEnded])) AS [Average Length In Days For Completion For Non-Disabled Users]
FROM TableName
LEFT JOIN [Calendar] AS Cal ON Cal.[Date] = [DateStarted]
WHERE [DateStarted] >= '20220101'
GROUP BY [MonthName]
ORDER BY [MonthName]
```

How can I merge both these queries together so that there is one record per month for each average? If I do a subquery, it returns 2 rows per month with the non-disability people having NULL records as I have to group it by disability.

Comment: How does the last query exclude people with a disability? At first glance it appears to not check for disabilities. Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 0):

Since [`avg`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/avg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) ignores `null` values you can combine the two queries using *conditional aggregation*:

```
SELECT [MonthName]
, AVG( D.DAYS ) AS [Average Length In Days For Completion For All Users]
, AVG( CASE WHEN T.[Disability] = 'Y' THEN D.DAYS END ) AS [Average Length In Days For Completion For Disabled Users]
, AVG( CASE WHEN T.[Disability] <> 'Y' THEN D.DAYS END ) AS [Average Length In Days For Completion For Non-Disabled Users]
FROM TableName
LEFT JOIN #Temp AS T ON T.[Number] = [Number]
LEFT JOIN [Calendar] AS Cal ON Cal.[Date] = [DateStarted]
CROSS APPLY ( DATEDIFF( DAY, [DateStarted], [DateEnded] ) AS DAYS ) AS D
WHERE [DateStarted] >= '20220101'
GROUP BY [MonthName]
ORDER BY [MonthName]
```

The semantics of `Disability` were not provided by the OP so I have taken the liberty of making an uneducated guess that `'Y'` and something else are present for all users, a fact belied by the use of `left outer join`. Some tweaking of the `case` conditions may be needed to make the logic correct, e.g. checking for `T.[Disability] IS NULL OR T.[Disability] <> 'Y'`.

Note: Best practice would be to use a table alias on each column reference. Since the OP declined to share DDL for the tables I have not attempted to add the aliases.